# Linux bash script (syntax error near unexpected token 'elif'

Tags: linux, bash

```
echo "Wollen Sie mit einer Benutzererstellung beginnen? Ja(y), Nein(n)"
    read text
    if [ $text == "y" ];
        then echo "Wilkommen zum Benutzererstellungsskript"
        #Username hinzufügen
        echo "Wie soll der Benutzer heissen?"
        read username
        if grep -q 
        echo "Soll der User ein Homeverzeichnis haben? Ja(y), Nein(n)"
        read homeverzeichnis
        if [ $homeverzeichnis == "y" ];
            then sudo useradd -m $username
            echo "Sie haben $username erfolgreich mit Homeverzeichnis erstellt."
        elif [ $homeverzeichnis == "n" ];
            then sudo useradd $username
            echo "Sie haben $username erfolgreich ohne Homeverzeichnis erstellt."
        fi

    #Passwort setzen
    echo "Wollen Sie dem Benutzer noch ein Passwort geben? Ja(y), Nein(n)"
    read password
    if [ $password == "y" ];
        then sudo passwd $username
    elif [ $passwd == "n" ];
        then echo "Dann halt nicht"
    fi

    #in Gruppe hinzufügen
    int i = "1";
    while [ i == 1 ];
        do
            echo "Welcher Gruppe soll der Benutzer $username hinzugefügt werden?1,2,3,4,5"
            echo "1. Root"
            echo "2. HR"
            echo "3. Basis"
            echo "4. Design"
            echo "5. RW"
            read group

            if [[ $group == "1" ]];
                then usermod -aG $username root
                i = "0"
            elif [[ $group == "2" ]];
                then usermod -aG $username HR
                i = "0"
            elif [[ $group == "3" ]];
                then usermod -aG $username Basis
                i = "0"
            elif [[ $group == "4" ]];
                then usermod -aG $username Design
                i = "0"
            elif [[ $group == "5" ]];
                then usermod -aG $username RW
                i = "0"
            else
                i = "1"
            fi
        done
elif [ $text == "n" ];
    echo "Das Programm wird beendet!"
    exit 1
fi
```

At the start the script asks you if you want do start it or not. But when you type something in and press enter this error comes:

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `then` after `if grep -q`. http://shellcheck.net would catch that.

Answer (score 0):

echo "Wollen Sie mit einer Benutzererstellung beginnen? Ja(y), Nein(n)"
    read text
    if [ "$text" -eq y ];
        then echo "Wilkommen zum Benutzererstellungsskript"
        #Username hinzufügen
        echo "Wie soll der Benutzer heissen?"
        read username
        if grep -q;
        then
        echo "Soll der User ein Homeverzeichnis haben? Ja(y), Nein(n)"
        read homeverzeichnis
        if [ "$homeverzeichnis" -eq y ];
            then sudo useradd -m $username
            echo "Sie haben $username erfolgreich mit Homeverzeichnis erstellt."
        elif [ "$homeverzeichnis" -eq n ];
            then sudo useradd $username
            echo "Sie haben $username erfolgreich ohne Homeverzeichnis erstellt."
        fi

```
    #Passwort setzen
    echo "Wollen Sie dem Benutzer noch ein Passwort geben? Ja(y), Nein(n)"
    read password
    if [ "$password" -eq y ];
        then sudo passwd $username
    elif [ "$password" -eq n ];
        then echo "Dann halt nicht"
    fi

    #in Gruppe hinzufügen
    int i = "1"
    while [ "$i" -eq 1 ];
        do
            echo "Welcher Gruppe soll der Benutzer $username hinzugefügt werden?1,2,3,4,5"
            echo "1. Root"
            echo "2. HR"
            echo "3. Basis"
            echo "4. Design"
            echo "5. RW"
            read group

            if [ "$group" -eq 1 ];
                then usermod -aG $username root
                i = "0"
            elif [ "$group" -eq 2 ];
                then usermod -aG $username HR
                i = "0"
            elif [ "$group" -eq 3 ];
                then usermod -aG $username Basis
                i = "0"
            elif [ "$group" -eq 4 ];
                then usermod -aG $username Design
                i = "0"
            elif [ "$group" -eq 5 ];
                then usermod -aG $username RW
                i = "0"
            else
                i = "1"
            fi
        done
elif [ "$text" -eq n ];
    then echo "Das Programm wird beendet!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Thanks guys but now I got another Problem... And I dont know whats the matter:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHwEK.jpg)

Comment: First, Stack Overflow is an English-language site; please post answers in English. Second, answers should not include follow-up questions. If you have an additional question, please start a new post. If you need a clarification of an answer, use a comment on that answer. If you need to clarify your question in a way that does not invalidate any current answers, edit the question directly.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry so the code should also be in english? And I though i can just add my new problems in the same question cant i?

Comment: No; if you have a follow-up question, post a *new* question. This site isn't for back-and-forth discussions about a particular piece of code; it's is intended as a general reference where one can find answers to questions similar to one you might ask.

Comment: The code (comments and variable names, that is) itself doesn't absolutely need to be in English, although it may be helpful for those reading the question. (My own understanding of German is much worse than I would like it to be.)

Answer (score -1):

Doppelte Klammern und doppelte Ist-Gleich Zeichen gibt nur beim Vertifizieren von Daten und bei Java.
Beispiel:

```
if [[ "$TIME" =~ ^[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ]]; then
```

Opps sorry, here an english anwser...
The following code is not valide.

```
   if [[ $group == "1" ]];
```

It has to look like the following...

```
if [ "$group" -eq 1 ]; then
elif [ "$group" -eq 2 ]; then
```

Here is a [god like guide](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Shell/Bash-Skripting-Guide_f%C3%BCr_Anf%C3%A4nger/) for bash-scripting with german documentation xD

Comment: So what does '==' mean ? and what does '[[' and ']]' mean ? Variables that have no double quotes can bypass tests when having no value. This is by far not a valide code.

Comment: The question is tagged `bash`: `[[ ... ]]` is a conditional command, and `==` is a valid operator for string equality and pattern matching. Word splitting and pathname expansion are not applied to parameter expansions on the lefthand operand of `==`, so quoting is optional.